# CMD with icacls issue for windows 10 upgrade - invalid parameters

Tags: cmd, sql-grant, icacls

I'm trying to upgrade my laptop to windows 10 but it says my system reserved partition is low on available size so i'm following microsoft solution on the internet and somehow got stuck with these commands. for your information, i'm stuck on the windows 7 with MBR partition part 1j.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/3086249#bookmark-w7mbr

i typed `whoami` in the cmd window and it reads:

`alanong-pc\alan ong`

thereafter, I entered `icacls .\grant alanong-pc\alan ong:F/t`

with the results: `Invalid parameter "alanong-pc\alan"`

i tried numerous way and researched on the internet but none works for me i tried quotes or even double backslashes and none works.

Could you guys help me out here thanks in advance!

Comment: Question would be a better fit for [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) perhaps?

Comment: Parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes. The error message tells you this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is this:

```
icacls . /grant alanong-pc\"alan ong":F /t
```

Note that there is a space before the **/grant** and the **/t**.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for spaces in your parameters and surround them in quotes, also /t is separated by space:

```
icacls . /grant "alanong-pc\alan ong":F /t
```

Originaly answered on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1101182/cmd-with-icacls-issue-for-windows-10-upgrade-invalid-parameters/1101197#1101197)